# Intercept AWS S3 requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hi I am looking to implement a workflow like this

`Input-files => S3 (regular/multipart) uploader => My-processing-server => Output-files => S3 (regular/multipart) uploader => AWS-S3-server`

In other words, the `Input-files` are expected to be uploaded to `My-processing-server` as S3 requests so that `My-processing-server` can process `Input-files` to generate `Output-files`, which are then uploaded to the `AWS-S3-server`.

I would like to know how I can setup an in-house `My-processing-server`, which can accept `Input-files` via S3 APIs.

Note: I noticed the [client configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/client-config.html) allows configuration of `proxy*` fields. But if I understood correctly, it simply lets the traffic to be passed via proxy server without introducing any processing steps on the proxy server or changing the file sizes etc.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. If you are asking if you can build a server that implements the S3 APIs then yes, you can do that. Many object storage vendors have done exactly that to allow existing S3 clients to target their S3-like services.

Comment: @jarmod: can you please any server side software they can be used to receive and process S3 APIs

Answer (score 1):

You can't really intercept API calls to S3 (if I'm understanding what you're asking) and have your own API receive the calls - the ability to do that would break the trust chain for S3's API call.

You have two options here for doing something similar to what you're asking:

1. Create your own API, and have users upload to your API to process the files. This has the benefit of being more synchronous for your users (I.e., your processing happens immediately on upload, before the file is available on S3), however it has the downside of forcing you to handle all scaling of the service that's doing the transformation. If you mess up that scaling, user file uploads will fail in times of heavy load. This could looks like plain old ec2 server, an ECS container, a lambda+api gateway, etc. There are myriad ways to host a web server.
2. Create an SQS queue that listens for S3 files that are uploaded to S3. Your users would then upload the file directly to S3 (make sure you look up signed URLs for this if it's a non-trusted user), and you'd listen to the SQS queue for understanding when to process a message (creating your output file). In this case, you'd likely want to store your output file into a separate S3 bucket to avoid a processing loop. This has the benefit of allowing you to rely on S3's built-in scaling to handle times of large load, but it has the downside that your processing is asynchronous from your users. If they upload a file, they wouldn't see it immediately as an output.

There are other soft things that could impact your design (such as whether or not you allow upload of really large files, which would push you to solution #2), but those are the two common design patterns for what you're asking for.

Comment: Okay, I agree the word "intercept" might not be very clear. I explain it in point 2 below. My objectives are:
1) the users communicate to `My-processing-server` via S3 API. In future, if users want to skip processing offered by `My-processing-server`, they will still be compatible to upload files directly to `AWS-S3-server`.
2) only intercept few types of S3 APIs (eg. upload requests), use the internal data payload to use for my processing and then upload. For other types of S3 APIs (list objects etc) my server simply pass through to AWS-S3-Server and push responses back to users.

Comment: I think what you want is option 2 above, from a design pattern perspective. Your API would discard any events in the SQS queue that aren't new objects, then you can pass though *all* traffic to S3 (including uploads). The events are what you'd capture to process the files.